Provisionary profile issue while automatically signing my Flutter app on Xcode
I'm having issues while automatically signing the app like the flutter's official youtube tutorial says. When chosen automatically manage signing and entering my apple dev id as the team, I get 2 issues:
1)"Your team has no devices from which to generate a provisioning profile. Connect a device to use or manually add device IDs in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. https://developer.apple.com/account/"
2)"No profiles for 'com.myappdomain.myappname' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.myappdomain.myappname'."
Now, I've already entered my bundle id to my dev account as the tutorial said and I'm obviously using an apple device since I'm already on Xcode, I can't figure out what the issue is here.
Any help is deeply appreciated as I'm unable to find any solutions for this. There seems to be a github issue that is 2 weeks old and he says he just changed the team to a valid team name but I'm not part of a dev team. Am I missing something here?
Here is my flutter build ipa:
Archiving com.myappdomain.myappname...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 12345678
Running Xcode build...
Xcode archive done.                                          8.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'com.myappdomain.myappname' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
'com.myappdomain.myappname'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to
xcodebuild.
/Users/username/development/flutter_projects/myappname/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
It appears that there was a problem signing your application prior to installation on the device.
Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
Also try selecting 'Product > Build' to fix the problem.
Encountered error while archiving for device.
I tried to get my app ready for publishing and I was expecting that the steps in the official tutorial would be enough.

You have to add both profile and provisional certificate from console.
please visit this for more info, https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
